# Getting NaN only on certain dates when converting with getTime()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a react app with firebase firestore for the db, the app stores a date field obtained from a datepicker in dd/mm/yyyy format as a string. I need to sort by dates and I'm converting dates to correctly sort by numbers with:

```
new Date(myDate).getTime()
```

But I'm getting NaN only on certain dates, for example:

```
01/12/2017 // 1484190000000
02/11/2017 // 1486782000000
22/08/2017 // NaN
```

Any idea???

Comment: In JS, Date constructor expects values in `MM/DD/YYYY` or `YYYY/MM/DD` but not in `DD/MM/YYYY`. You can try a simple trick: `new Date(dateStr.split('/').reverse().join('/'))`

Comment: In `22/08/2017`, `22` is not a valid month. Hence `NaN`.

Comment: how about considering using `react-moment` ?

Comment: @Rajesh—the built-in date parser is not required to support any of those formats so it's not sensible to expect that it will.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateArr = '22/08/2017'.split('/');
new Date(dateArr[2], --dateArr[1], dateArr[0]).getTime();
```

Try this. 22/08/2017 - wrong format, need 08/22/2017

Comment: My first decision was `new Date('22/08/2017'.split('/').reverse().join('-')).getTime();` but i dont know, that date format will affect the result. So i make quick edits.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Latish your reply help me!